# Notifying UI once the reference of an Object is changed

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to bind the selected part from a part list that is inside an object as an ObservableCollection.

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource getPartConverter}">
            <Binding Path="PartType" ElementName="PartDisplayUserControl"/>
            <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=local:MainWindow}" Path="ViewModelForParts"/>
        </MultiBinding>
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

Once the PartList (ObservableCollection) changes it is not triggering the Converter (getPartConverter). But once the PartType changes, it triggers the converter and finds the correct part. How can I trigger the converter once the part list is changed?

The code for the ViewModelForParts is as follows:

```
public class PartConfiguratorViewModel : PropertyChangedViewModelBase
    {
        private ObservableCollection<PartData> partList;
        public ObservableCollection<PartData> PartList 
        { 
            get => partList;
            set => SetField(ref partList, value); 
        }

        public PartConfiguratorViewModel()
        {
            PartList = new ObservableCollection<PartData>();
        }
    }
```

Note: The setField command has the Property Change event. Also, all the properties inside the PartData Object have the same event as well.

Comment: I don't see any XAML binding to the actual `PartList`   Where is that? If you want a control to be updated when an `ObservableCollection` changes, you generally must bind that collection to some form of `ItemsControl` via the `ItemsSource` property  Then, if you want each item in the control to show the contents of one part,  you set its `ItemTemplate` appropriately.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I found the issue! The binding is working however I couldn't understand why the "INotifyCollectionChanged" of the Observable collection is not working for me. Once in the multi binding I add another binding to the collection's count then it triggers the converter. If I add the following binding to the multi binding it works: `<Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=local:MainWindow}" Path="ViewModelForParts.PartList.Count"/>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should bind to a property that actually gets set when the collection is updated, such as for example the `Count` property:

```
<Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=local:MainWindow}"
    Path="ViewModelForParts.Count"/>
```

Binding to the collection property itself will only trigger the converter if you set the `PartList` property to another collection (which defeats the purpose of using an `ObservableCollection<T>` over another kind of collection that doesn't raise the `INotifyCollectionChanged` event)